# Can I use Ionic 5 without Capacitor? Should I just use Quasar?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, quasar

I've been playing with Ionic 5 recently looking to build a production app with it. Absolutely amazing framework... but Capacitor is becoming frustrating to work with and Ionic's live code push pricing makes no sense.

A lot of Cordova plugins including code push to WebRTC on iOS and more are not working with Capacitor. I'm at a crossroad of learning Vue and switching to Quasar so I can use only Cordova without Capacitor. It's been some time since 1.0 was released and a lot of Cordova plugins are incompatible with Capacitor.

It seems like Capacitor is tightly coupled to Ionic 5 and there's no way to choose between it and Cordova like Quasar. Does anyone have any other thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: Actually, most of your assumptions are wrong. Ionic and Capacitor are definitely intended to be used together, but they are not tightly coupled. You don't have to use Capacitor if you don't want to. You can use Cordova with Ionic. Also, Ionic and Capacitor are open source and don't cost anything to deploy. Ionic does however provide a lot of paid tools and plans to make development and deployment easier.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke. I meant the live code push pricing is pretty unreasonable. Will edit.

How do I use Ionic 5 with just Cordova? Will Cordova still be relevant in the coming years?

Comment: How? Only use Cordova plugins, and then build with Cordova https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build Capacitor was built to be Cordova's "successor" according to Ionic, but in my opinion Cordova will still be relevant for years.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. I got Cordova up and running and it's awesome. Capacitor is definitely too young atm for more advanced apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ionic without Capacitor. If, as in your case, you need to use Cordova plugins that do not work with Capacitor, you can either look out for their Capacitor equivalent in the official repository, or elsewhere, but if you will be relying on a lot of Cordova plugins, it is best to just use Cordova + Ionic from the ground up.

There is already an excellent number of Cordova plugins for almost anything you may want to do, and the Capacitor community is working pretty hard to bring equivalent Cordova plugins to Capacitor.